# Arch Linux GRUB installation fail on Virtualbox

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, grub

I was trying Arch Linux in a virtual machine, I am at the part of installing grub bootloader.

When I try to install grub into "`/dev/sda1`" it shows the following:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system ‘ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Note: I am using `ext4`, not `ext2`

Note: I tried using `grub-install --force /dev/sda1`, it showed the same errors and a fake success message at the end, like how it could be without errors if it showed me errors, I guess it will not work. I don't wanna risk trying to reboot and see.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I joined a Linux discord server and asked about it, they said I should've wrote "/dev/sda" instead of "/dev/sda1"

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that error is because you're likely booting into a *partition* image that was converted into a disk, as opposed to a *disk* image; an easy way to confirm this is to run lsblk once you've booted in (with super grub2 disk) and see if you get the following:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    5G  0 disk /
```

You'll notice that the disk itself is the mountpoint, as opposed to the following expected disk and partition tree:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    5G  0 part /
```

If you're using something like gnome-disks (gnome-disk-utility) to create the disk image, then use:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw yourdisk.img newvirtualdisk.vdi --format VDI
```

Doing this will copy over the bootloader as well if it existed on the original disk, otherwise now you'll be able to boot in with super grub2 disk and then run sudo grub-install /dev/sda without any issues!